# Downloading a file with utf-8 characters using web2py fails

Tags: python, utf-8, urllib, web2py

Many thanks for reading:
I am developing a small app (hobby) to upload automatically files and be published in the web using **python** in the local machine and **web2py** in the WEB

Filenames uploaded have greek utf8 encoded characters i.e.

> New_Υπολογιστικό_φύλλο_OpenDocument.ods

In the default web2py controller I use the following to:
1: Grasp the filename clicked in the view link  and
2: Send the filename to browser:

```
def myaction():
     import os
     import urllib
     path  =request.folder + 'files_to_transfer' 
      ###### my folder where files are uploated######
     #change cwd to path   
     cwd = os.chdir(path)
     filename = urllib.quote_plus(request.vars['z']) 
     return response.stream(filename)
```

In default controller I use as well the following code to prepare the filenames list used by the view :

```
def index():


import os
import json

path  =request.folder + 'files_to_transfer' 

#change cwd to path

cwd = os.chdir(path)
filenames = []
filenames_excluded = ['httpserver.log', 'server_files.json' ]
for file in os.listdir(u'.'):
    if file not in filenames_excluded:
        filenames.append ((file).encode('utf-8'))
   return dict(message=filenames)
```

and in the View I use:

```
    <html>
   <head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
   <body>

       <h2>
           {{for x in range(len(message)):}}

           {{=A('click me', callback=URL('myaction', args=['x', 'y'], vars=dict(z=message[x])))}}
           {{=message[x]}}<br />{{pass}}
        </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

The links have the following form:

> click me New WinRAR archive.rar
>   click me New Υπολογιστικό φύλλο OpenDocument.ods
>   click me New_WinRAR_archive.rar  etc...

**Problem**: Only filenames containing english characters are downloaded. 
Use of **urllib.quote_plus** does its job and produces and link like:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/webappfiletransfer/default/myaction/x/y?z=New_%CE%A5%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C_%CF%86%CF%8D%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF_OpenDocument.ods

but **response.stream** returns for a **404 NOT FOUND** error.
I have tried variations with **urlencode** but to no avail.
Any thoughts or comments are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I have tried the use of:

```
import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem by giving more attention in the **404 HTTP error**. Although the file existed, it could not be found.

By viewing the web2py error tickets, I found out that

> response.stream(filename)

was trying to locate filename:

> New_%CE%A5%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C_%CF%86%CF%8D%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF_OpenDocument.ods

and not

> New_Υπολογιστικό_φύλλο_OpenDocument.ods

So I revised the code as below and added two response.headers to allow for file download as well:

```
import os
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')     
path=request.folder + 'files_to_transfer'
cwd = os.chdir(path)
##################################################################
filename =((request.vars['z'])).decode('utf-8') 
##########urllib.quote or quote_plus is not needed in my case and ...
#########trasforms the filename to a form not suitable
response.headers['ContentType'] ="application/octet-stream";
response.headers['Content-Disposition']="attachment; filename="+filename


return response.stream((filename))
```

**Main problems were:**

1. use of urllib.quote_plus was unneccessary and problematic in this case since it was tranforming the filename as it should but in this case this was a problem
2. There was the need to decode the filename - already utf-8 encoded- coming from the view in order to be found and so the usage of **.decode('utf-8')**

**EDIT : Please note that without**

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

I am getting a server error. So probably you will have to use it.

Hope someone finds it usefull.